# What package provides the MSCVR100D.DLL debug symbols?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debug-symbols

**What debug symbol package provides the debug symbols for MSCVR100D.DLL?**

I have the Windows 7 [RTM (7600)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463028) and [SP1 (7601)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyId=c3202ce6-4056-4059-8a1b-3a9b77cdfdda) debug symbols installed for both the x86 and AMD64 platform which provides the symbols for the various OS libraries I need (e.g. kernel32.dll, user32.dll, ntdll.dll, etc.). Using the Microsoft Public Symbol servers, I see that the specific PDB I'm looking for is:

> `MicrosoftPublicSymbols\msvcr100d.i386.pdb\9CF06FEE2BF04A2C8C8EFAFB627A3F421\msvcr100d.i386.pdb`

**I want to install a local symbol package for offline availability like I've done with the OS symbols**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a specific download that provides these symbols, however Visual Studio Professional and higher (I'm unsure about Express editions) ships with the debug information in the following location:

> <path to VS install>\VC\lib

which on most machines is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib

I would have expected these symbols to have been picked up auto-magically by VS, but I had to manually add them to my symbol path by doing:

> - Debug->Options and Settings->Symbol
> - Click the folder icon to add a symbol folder
> - Provide the path  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>     10.0\VC\lib
> - Check the box next to it to enable it
> - Click 'Load All Symbols'
> - Click 'OK'